# Is there logical loophole here?

Tags: logic, computer-science, boolean-logic

I need to execute a piece of code which is like this

```
if(condition 1)
{
    set variable to false
}
else if (condition 2)
{
    set variable to false
} else {
    set variable to true
}
```

Is this the same as

```
 if(!condition 1)
 {
   if(!condition2)
   {
     variable = true
   }
 }
```

Can the results of these two differ under any circumstance? Is there a systematic proof to this?

Comment: `variable = !(condition 1) && !(condition 2)`

Comment: It's not the same thing as you never set the variable to false in the second variant.

Comment: If the variable can be assumed to already be false, then yes, they are the same.  Proofs would have to do with the equivalences of nested branches to logical operators.

Answer (score 4):

The second snippet is almost equivalent to the first one - in case you can assume that `variable` is initialized to `false` unless otherwise set, which may work in some programming languages, but is probably a bad idea, and you had better explicitly initialize it to `false` before calling this snippet.

Note, by the way, that this entire expression could be dramatically shortened by using logical operators:

```
variable = !(condition1) && !(condition2);
```

Or arguably more elegantly:

```
variable = !(condition1 || condition2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question

> Can the results of these two differ under any circumstance?

is pretty broad, and I can think of at least four circumstances where the results of the two snippets might differ. This is assuming, as others have pointed out, that your second example is preceded by the following initialization:

```
variable = false
```

Without the above initialization step, many programming languages would create `variable` without automatically initializing it, meaning that its value is indeterminate.

After presenting the four cases, I will show at the end a proof that the logic in both snippets is identical.

#### Case 1: Side Effects when evaluating conditions

The first circumstance where these might differ is if the programming language allows "side effects" to occur when evaluating conditions.

In the C language, for example, the condition might be the result of an assignment statement, which can change the state of the variables being tested.

Consider the following example. If we initialize `variable` to `false` in both snippets, and let Condition 1 be `((variable = !variable) == true)`and Condition 2 be `((variable = !variable) == false)` (which has the side effect of changing the value of `variable`), then in the following C code:

```
bool variable1 = false;
if (((variable1 = !variable1) == true)) {
    variable1 = false;
}
else if (((variable1 = !variable1) == false)) {
    variable1 = false;
}
else {
    variable1 = true;
}

bool variable2 = false;
if (!((variable2 = !variable2) == true)) {
    if (!((variable2 = !variable2) == false)) {
        variable2 = true;
    }
}
```

the result will be `variable1 == false` and `variable2 == true`, which demonstrates a case in which the results differ.

#### Case 2: Overloaded assignment operator

In the C++ language, the assignment operator (`=`) can be overloaded, which means that its entire meaning can be changed to something different than it appears. So it would be possible to define an assignment operator where

```
variable = false;
```

sometimes results in `variable` being assigned the value `false`, but under some conditions results in `variable` actually being assigned the value `true`. This is a bizarre example, but your question was

> Can the results of these two differ under any circumstance?

so here I'm assuming that "any circumstance" allows that basic assumptions (such as `variable = false` really means `variable = false`) can be set aside. It's not hard to imagine a scenario where an assignment operator could be designed to cause the two cases to produce different results. One might argue that here I'm thinking too far outside the box, but in the real world we have languages such as C++ that sometimes really do behave differently than one might expect.

#### Case 3: Conditions are Timing-Sensitive

A given optimizing compiler might conceivably recognize both of your snippets as being equivalent, and might actually compile them to identical machine code. It's probably more likely that most compilers will produce different machine code for the two snippets.  If the machine code is different, then the amount of time to execute might differ between the two snippets. If Condition 2 tests the value of a timer, it's possible that the timer might have a different value at the moment of the test in the first snippet than it would in the second snippet, which might produce a different decision, producing a different result in `variable`.

#### Case 4: More Than One Thread

In programs that employ preemptive multitasking, sometimes programmers forget they are no longer working in a closed system. If a task is a thread, and if `variable` and/or the elements that make up either Condition 1 or Condition 2 are write-accessible in two asynchronous threads, it is possible that either snippet could be interrupted by another thread, changing the state of the variables being evaluated or set, causing unpredictable results.

#### Case 5: No tricks

If we assume that we are talking about a closed static system with no surprises like the ones above, and that all you really wanted was a simple proof that the two snippets were logically equivalent, then create a truth table considering all possibilities:

```
         Inputs               Output
Condition 1  Condition 2    "variable"
-----------  -----------    ----------
   False        False          True
   False        True           False
   True         False          False
   True         True           False
```

If you run these inputs through both of your code snippets, I believe you will find that both snippets will produce the same results shown in the Output column in the above table. This would serve as a systematic proof that both are identical.

This table, and your two code snippets, happen to represent the behavior of a `NOR` function.